# How can I write a certain number of characters per line out of a string literal?

Tags: string, c-strings, string-literals

I am learning C and trying to figure out strings. How do I break down a simple string literal to print out 6 chars per line? I'm kinda confused if my approach is on track. Thanks!

For example:

```
   char someString = "Hello world, I like to fly high like a cloud!";
   char * temp = malloc(30);

   temp = someString;          //so I can manipulate a string literal

   int count = 6;

   for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
   {
      if(i<count)
      {      
         printf("%c", temp[i]);        
      }
      if(i == count)
      {
         printf("\n");
         count = count + count;
      }
    }

    free(temp);    //prevent memory leak
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, a string is actually an array of characters, so it must be declared as an array... which just means you need to insert `[]` after `SomeString` in your first line. And since you are not modifying the string, there is no need to make a copy... but if you do, you cannot copy a string (which, again, is an array) with a simple assignment. You would have to use the `strcpy` function, or better yet, `strdup`, which also handles the memory allocation for you.

Your logic in the `for` loop is almost correct, except that you are doubling count on each iteration... which is fine for the first two iterations, in which count is 6 and 12, but then on the third iteration it's 24. Instead of `count = count + count;`, you want `count += 6;` If you like, you can define the character block size as a macro, so it can be easily changed: put the line `#define STEP 6` near the top of your program. Then change `int count = 6;` to `int count = STEP;`, and `count += 6;` to `count += STEP;`

Comment: BTW, if you want to be sure the original string is not modified, declare it as `const char` instead of `char`.